# How to handle validation (email along with custom user field) user registration via REST API?

Tags: 8, users

I am using Drupal 8 default REST API end points for user registration and login services as per link below provided

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services#users

[image: user registration fields along with custom field]

How to validate user with email along with custom filed values which I created in the user profile ? I mean if both email and custom field value already exists, then throw an error to stop registration; if not, then allow registration.

**Note:** I have tried with entity queries via form alter to validate but it is working fine when registrations happens via website but it's not working registrations happens via REST API POST Method.

Comment: Please remember to ask just one distinct question per post; I removed the second question, but it can be asked separately. Just make sure you include proper details about what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. Thanks

Comment: @parvateesam Please check Entity Validation API for your first problem. and I will provide you one post which will allow you to create new Custom Service for you: https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-custom-rest-resources-for-post-methods-drupal-8

Comment: @AshwinP thanks for the suggestion validation we can achieve by  Entity Validation I will check that and I have reviewed the Link which you have given for custom rest resource i.e. for node creation with default fields is there any Link for user creation with including custom fields ?